# Node.js get value from end of url

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there a way for me to create a URL like this: `http://localhost/example/143` and use `143` as an id to fetch content? I do not want question marks or other things like this. An example website like this is imgur which doesn't use question marks.

I have looked for other options, but all of their questions requires `?=somequery` in order for it to work.

Thanks

Comment: Can you describe the context? Is this for an express.js request, or what exactly are you trying?

Comment: @mmm It would be for an express.js request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use req.params as in express documentation

Route path: `/users/:userId/books/:bookId`
Request URL: `http://localhost:3000/users/34/books/8989`
req.params: `{ "userId": "34", "bookId": "8989" }`

**In case of using raw http**
for using with raw http module you can use  `str.split("/")[2]`;

```
var http = require('http');
function handleRequest(request, response){
    response.end('It Works!! Path Hit: ' + request.url);
    var str = request.url;
    var exampleId = str.split("/")[2];

}
var server = http.createServer(handleRequest);
server.listen(8080, function(){});
```

Answer (score 3):

Use express.js named route parameters: http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-parameters

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is what's referred to as a restful web api implemented with routing  You'll typically want to build your site in a MVC (**M**odel **V**iew **C**ontroller) framework to get this functionality.  Express.js is new hotness on the block - especially in the context of javascript and node.js categories tied to this question - but there are others out there as well. Ruby on Rails made MVC and restful routing popular, and MS has ASP.NET MVC.  PHP even has CodeIgniter and others I'm sure, and Angular2 is Google's MVC baby at the moment.

The point is, there are many frameworks to choose from that will give you the restful URL routing you're looking for.  Find one you like, and run with it!